# Is there a way to vectorize this function or improve its efficiency

Tags: python, pandas

This loop is intended to match subjects in df2 to subjects in df1 with a 1:4 ratio. The key here is randomly selecting subjects while avoiding redundancy. No subject should be matched twice. df1 has a few thousand subjects, whereas df2 has over one million. Every subject in df1 will be matched to four subjects in df2, those who aren't matched will be left out. Does anyone have ideas for improving its efficiency? An approach that also conserves RAM would be ideal. Thanks.

```
for x in range(4): # 1:4 matching
    for index, row in df1.iterrows():
        temp = df2.loc[(df2['matched'] != 1) & (df2['race_ethnicity'] == row['race_ethnicity']) & (df2['age'] == row['age']) & ((df2['date1'] > row['date2']) | (df2['date1'].isna()))]
        a = temp.sample()
        a['matched_subject'] = row['subject_id']
        a['matched'] = '1'
        a['possible_matches'] = len(temp)
```

It can be simplified to this, but I'd prefer to continue using the 'possible_matches' row for diagnostics.

```
for x in range(4): # 4 because 1:4 matching
    for index, row in df1.iterrows():
        a = df2.loc[(df2['matched_subject']=='') & (df2['race_ethnicity'] == row['race_ethnicity']) & (df2['age'] == row['age']) & ((df2['date1'] > row['date2']) | (df2['date1'] == 0))].sample()
        a['matched_subject'] = row['pid']
```

Clarifications: All rows are unique in both DataFrames, representing a list of subjects that will be compared in survival analysis. Date1 is the datetime of outcome variable event, is present for a fraction of subjects in both DataFrames. Date 2 is the datetime of independent variable event, present for all df1 subjects and no df2 subjects. Sample inputs include:

- subject_id (numeric)
- race_ethnicity (str, 3 categories)
- age (numeric)
- Matched (binary, indicates if a df2 subject has been matched to one in df1)
- Matched_subject (numeric, the subject_id of the matched subject)
- date1 (datetime. outcome variable for survival models, present for some and not others in both dataframes)
- date2 (datetime for event that is independent variable. Everyone in df1 has a date2, nobody in df2 has a date2. A df1 subject's date2 is their index date for survival analysis, and also serves as index date for their matched subjects who have no date2 variable)

We want to match four subjects in df2 for every one in df1. Date2 in df1 will be the index date for matched subjects in df2, hence we have a condition to ensure that date1 (outcome event) in df2 doesn't occur before date2 in df1 (index event)

Here is an example of two df2 subjects matched to df1. Also with an unmatched df1 and df2 subject. The real df2 is large enough to match all df1 subjects with great excess.

df1:

| subject_id | race_ethnicity | age | date1 | date2 | matched | matched_subject | possible_matches |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3a3r796e | Non-Hispanic white | 55 | (can be present in df1 or df2. if present, must be after date 2 in df1) | 2012-01-01 | 1 | 3a3r796e matching based on df1, therefore these are the same | only important for df2. not important for analysis, just a diagnostic value |
| 1234abcd | Non-Hispanic black | 58 | 2017-01-01 | 2016-01-01 | 0 |  |  |

df2:

| subject_id | race_ethnicity | age | date1 | date2 | matched | matched_subject | possible_matches |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5c69a756 | Non-Hispanic white | 55 | 2015-01-01 | (cannot be present in df2, by definition) | 1 | 3a3r796e | 571 |
| 7as89f75 | Non-Hispanic white | 55 |  |  | 1 | 3a3r796e | 571 |
| 6376asef | Hispanic | 42 | 2010-01-01 |  | 0 |  |  |

Comment: Can you include some sample inputs please? I can guess your intentions but I'd rather get your requirements clearly defined. Also: are rows in `df1` unique?

Comment: Sure. All rows are unique in both DataFrames. Sample inputs include:
subject_id (numeric), race_ethnicity (str, 3 categories), age (numeric), date1 (datetime. outcome variable for survival models, present for some and not others), date2 (datetime for event that is independent variable, index date for subjects in df1, not present in df2). 

We want to match four subjects in df2 for every one in df1. Date2 in df1 will be the index date for matched subjects in df2, hence we have a condition to ensure that date1 (outcome event) in df2 doesn't occur before date2 in df1 (index event)

Comment: When I mentioned sample input, I meant a small snippet of data from `df1` and `df2` . You described the data without showing what they actually look like

Comment: I've added a couple of samples to the original question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's define some helper functions:

```py
def generate_data(df1_len, df2_len, seed=42):
    """Generate random data to help test different algorithms"""

    np.random.seed(seed)
    d2 = np.random.randint(0, 3000, size=df1_len)
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'subject_id': np.arange(df1_len),
        'race_ethnicity': np.random.choice(list('ABC'), df1_len),
        'age': np.random.randint(18, 100, df1_len),
        'date2': pd.Timestamp('2000-01-01') + pd.to_timedelta(d2, unit='D')
    })

    d1 = np.random.randint(0, 3000, size=int(df2_len * np.random.rand()))
    d1 = np.hstack([d2, np.repeat(np.nan, df2_len - len(d1))])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'subject_id': np.arange(df2_len),
        'race_ethnicity': np.random.choice(list('ABC'), df2_len),
        'age': np.random.randint(18, 100, df2_len),
        'date1': pd.Timestamp('2000-01-01') + pd.to_timedelta(d1, unit='D')
    })

    return df1, df2


def verify(df1, df2):
    """Verify that df1 and df2 are matched according to predefined rules"""
    
    tmp = df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on='subject_id', right_on='matched_subject', suffixes=('_1', "_2"))

    assert (tmp['race_ethnicity_1'] == tmp['race_ethnicity_2']).all(), 'race_ethnicity does not match'
    assert (tmp['age_1'] == tmp['age_2']).all(), 'age does not match'
    assert ((tmp['date1'] > tmp['date2']) | tmp['date1'].isna()).all(), 'date1 must be NaT or grater than date2'
    assert tmp.groupby('matched_subject').size().eq(4).all(), 'Invalid match ratio'
    
    print('All is good')
```

## The original solution

Allow me to make some changes in the interest of clarity. This version runs in
~28 seconds on my Mac:

```py
df1, df2 = generate_data(500, 100_000)

df2['matched'] = False
df2['matched_subject'] = None
df2['possible_matches'] = None

for x in range(4): # 1:4 matching
    for index, row in df1.iterrows():
        cond = (
            (df2['matched'] != 1) &
            (df2['race_ethnicity'] == row['race_ethnicity']) &
            (df2['age'] == row['age']) &
            ((df2['date1'] > row['date2']) | df2['date1'].isna())
        )
        temp = df2.loc[cond]
        if temp.empty:
            continue

        idx = temp.sample().index
        df2.loc[idx, 'matched_subject'] = row['subject_id']
        df2.loc[idx, 'matched'] = True
        df2.loc[idx, 'possible_matches'] = len(temp)
```

## An improved version

By taking out the outer loop (`for _ in range(4)`), you can improve performance
almost 4 times. The code below executed in 7s:

```py
df1, df2 = generate_data(5000, 1_000_000)

df2['matched'] = False
df2['matched_subject'] = None
df2['possible_matches'] = None

for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    cond = (
        (df2['matched'] != 1) &
        (df2['race_ethnicity'] == row['race_ethnicity']) &
        (df2['age'] == row['age']) &
        ((df2['date1'] > row['date2']) | df2['date1'].isna())
    )
    temp = df2.loc[cond]
    if temp.empty:
        continue

    idx = temp.sample(4).index
    df2.loc[idx, 'matched_subject'] = row['subject_id']
    df2.loc[idx, 'matched'] = True
    df2.loc[idx, 'possible_matches'] = len(temp)
```

## A further improved version

Taking the idea that working on multiple rows at once is faster than doing it
one at a time, we can loop based on *group* of rows with similar characteristics
rather than looping with individual rows. This code runs in 600ms or ~46x faster
than the original version:

```py
df1, df2 = generate_data(500, 100_000)

# Shuffle df2 so the matches will be random
df2 = df2.sample(frac=1)

# A dictionary to hold the result. Its keys are the indexes in df2 and its
# values are the indexes of df1
matches = {}

# We loop by group instead of individual row
grouped1 = df1.groupby(['race_ethnicity', 'age', 'date2'])
grouped2 = df2.groupby(['race_ethnicity', 'age'])

for (race_ethnicity, age, date2), subset1 in grouped1:
    # Get all rows from df2 that have the same `race_ethnicity` and `age`
    subset2 = grouped2.get_group((race_ethnicity, age))

    # pd.Series is slow. Switch to np.array for speed
    index2 = subset2.index.to_numpy()
    date1 = subset2['date1'].to_numpy()

    # Since all rows in subset1 and subset2 have already had the same
    # `race_ethnicity` and `age`, we only need to filter for two things:
    #   1. The relationship between `date1` and `date2`; and
    #   2. That the row in `df2` has NOT been matched before
    cond = (
        (np.isnan(date1) | (date1 > date2))
        & np.isin(index2, list(matches.keys()), invert=True)
    )

    # The match ratio
    index1 = np.repeat(subset1.index.to_numpy(), 4)

    # There is no way to know in advance how many rows in `subset2` will meet
    # the matching criteria:
    #   * Ideally: cond.sum() == len(index1), ie. 4 rows in `subset2` for every
    #     row in `subset1`
    #   * If there are more matches than we need: we will take the first `4 *
    #     len(subset1)` rows
    #   * If there are not enough matches: eg. 6 rows in `subset2` for 2 rows in
    #     `subset1`, some rows in `subset1` will have to accept < 4 matches
    n = min(cond.sum(), len(index1))

    matches.update({
        key: value for key, value in zip(index2[cond][:n], index1[:n])
    })

tmp = pd.DataFrame({
    'index2': matches.keys(),
    'index1': matches.values()
})
df2 = (
    df2.merge(tmp, how='left', left_index=True, right_on='index2')
       .merge(df1['subject_id'].to_frame('matched_subject'), how='left', left_on='index1', right_index=True)
       .drop(columns=['index1', 'index2'])
)
```

You can verify the solution:

```py
verify(df1, df2)
# Output: All is good
```